# Getting lock screen using VNC

Tags: xubuntu, vnc

Using xubuntu 14.04, connecting to the headless machine through VNC.
xvnc4 is auto-started and it's all fine. But when connecting with the VNC password I would like to get the login screen, or at least a question of login to unlock the machine instead of just entering a running session.
Also, using the lock screen in xfce is not working at all.

Comment: Try installing `xscreensaver`

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing:

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 
-forever -shared -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5901 
-localhost
```

Taken from here: http://robot.wpi.edu/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_an_XUbuntu_VNC_Server

It should load the vnc on the correct display